# Floats are not clearing

Tags: html, css

Divs on my header are overlapping unless I set a specific width, which I can't do. I've tried several different methods of clearing floats now, with no luck.

Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q0oc27t8/

And here is my navigation code:

```
.nav {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #496278;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    bottom: 3px;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 0.8vw 0 0.8vw;
    text-align: center;
}
```

What's the best way to go around this?

Comment: what you want to do, any output?

Comment: It's not your floats. It's that your `.inner` elements are absolutely positioned. Because of that your `.header-elements` have no size except for their padding.

Comment: There is overlap due to `position: absolute`, which takes the content out-of-flow.

Comment: Your code is pretty messy. Instead of using absolute positioned elements to vertical align the text inside the nav element, just use top and bottom padding and don't use any span or other inner elements. Position absolute doesn't follow the natural flow of the html, so that's why your nav elements are collapsing. It's because they're like "empty"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not your floats. It's that your `.inner` elements are absolutely positioned. Because of that they are taken out of the flow and your `.header-elements` have no size except for their padding.

It looks like you are trying to vertically and horizontally center those elements. You could use the `table` and `table-cell` display properties instead.

Relevant code:

```
.header-element {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    display:table;
    position:relative;
}

.header-element .inner {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Full code below:

```css
    body {
        background: gray;
    }
    /* ------ */
    /* Header */
    /* ------ */
    #header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 4vw;
        background: white;
        font-family: "fira-sans-2";
        /* Shadow */
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 7px 13px -4px rgba(110,110,110,1);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 7px 13px -4px rgba(110,110,110,1);
        box-shadow: 0px 7px 13px -4px rgba(110,110,110,1);
    }
    
    .header-element {
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        display:table;
        position:relative;
    }

    .header-element .inner {
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:center;
    }
    
    /* Logo */
    .logo {
        width: 3vw;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-right: 1vw;
    }
    
    .nav {
        border-bottom: 3px solid #496278;
        border: 1px dotted red;
        bottom: 3px;
        font-size: 1.1vw;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 0 0.8vw 0 0.8vw;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .nav .inner {
        margin-top: 3px;
    }
    
    /* No select */
    .noselect {
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
       -khtml-user-select: none;
         -moz-user-select: none;
          -ms-user-select: none;
              user-select: none;
    }
```

```html
<!-- Body -->
<body>
    <div id="header" class="noselect">
        <div class="header-element logo">
            <span class="inner">T</span>
        </div>
        <div class="header-element nav">
            <span class="inner">Map</span>
        </div>
        <div class="header-element nav">
            <span class="inner">Discover</span>
        </div>
        <div class="header-element nav">
            <span class="inner">Bucket</span>
        </div>
        <div class="header-element nav">
            <span class="inner">Plans</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The float are not your problem, all the text is absolutely positioned. This means that those elements are pulled out of the document flow and no longer wrap/stack correctly.

Instead of using `position: absolute` try using a little `padding` and `margin` to position each `.header-element`.

Comment: @Liam Macmillan while the accepted answer might work, it's not the best way to solve your problem. I suggest you to read and understand this one instead, so you won't have any problems in the future and your code will be clean and easy to understand and mantain (better)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `position: absolute` you used, it easy overlaps and in your case you don't need it.

If you change to this, you'll have a good start

```
.header-element .inner {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%); 
}
```

Code snippet

```css
    body {
        background: gray;
    }
    /* ------ */
    /* Header */
    /* ------ */
    #header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 4vw;
        background: white;
        font-family: "fira-sans-2";
        /* Shadow */
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 7px 13px -4px rgba(110,110,110,1);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 7px 13px -4px rgba(110,110,110,1);
        box-shadow: 0px 7px 13px -4px rgba(110,110,110,1);
    }
    
    .header-element {
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }

    .header-element .inner {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%); 
    }

    /* Logo */
    .logo {
        width: 3vw;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-right: 1vw;
    }
    
    .nav {
        border-bottom: 3px solid #496278;
        border: 1px dotted red;
        bottom: 3px;
        font-size: 1.1vw;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 0 0.8vw 0 0.8vw;
        text-align: center;
    }
        
    /* No select */
    .noselect {
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
       -khtml-user-select: none;
         -moz-user-select: none;
          -ms-user-select: none;
              user-select: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="header" class="noselect">
        <div class="header-element logo">
            <span class="inner">T</span>
        </div>
        <div class="header-element nav">
            <span class="inner">Map</span>
        </div>
        <div class="header-element nav">
            <span class="inner">Discover</span>
        </div>
        <div class="header-element nav">
            <span class="inner">Bucket</span>
        </div>
        <div class="header-element nav">
            <span class="inner">Plans</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to break the positioning of his `.header-element.logo .inner` element.

Comment: Cool. I just wanted to make sure the answer was complete.

Comment: Then the navigation text is not vertically or horizontally centred, hence the absolute positioning. Any way round this?

Comment: @LiamMacmillan Of course I have, updated my answer to fix that too.